# Combining 2 dictionaries and swap keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries like:

```
d1 = { 'AAPL' : [1, 2, 3] , 'MSFT' : [3, 4, 5] }

d2 = {1 : [], 2 : [], 3 : [], 4 : [], 5 : []}
```

and I need 1 dictionary like:

```
d3 = {1 : ['AAPL'], 2 : ['AAPL'], 3 : ['AAPL', 'MSFT'], 4 : ['MSFT'], 5 : ['MSFT']}
```

How do I get `d3`?

Comment: You didnt post your attempt code to do it. pls read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: StackOverlow isn't a code-writing service; please edit your honest attempt to code this into your question as a [mre] - include all information (including data) needed so anyone can paste your code into a file and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same problem you're having.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to StackOverflow and I take your comments into consideration for my next question. Thanks!

Comment: @mick_stackaccount check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona

Answer (score 1):

In your example your dictionary `d2` is useless. Still:

```
d1 = { 'AAPL' : [1, 2, 3] , 'MSFT' : [3, 4, 5] }

#d2 = {1 : [], 2 : [], 3 : [], 4 : [], 5 : []}

d3 = {}

for v in d1.values():
    for k in v:
        d3[k] = []

for k,v in d1.items():
    for x in v:
        d3[x].append(k)

print (d3)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['AAPL'], 2: ['AAPL'], 3: ['AAPL', 'MSFT'], 4: ['MSFT'], 5: ['MSFT']}
```

You can also do:

```
for k,v in d1.items():
    for x in v:
        if x not in d3.keys():
            d3[x] = []
        d3[x].append(k)

print (d3)
```

Here instead of doing the same loop twice (once to init, the other to fill), you test if your key exists or not and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A `collections.defaultdict` will do it nicely

```
d1 = {'AAPL': [1, 2, 3], 'MSFT': [3, 4, 5]}

result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d1.items():
    for x in v:
        result[x].append(k)

print(result)
# {1: ['AAPL'], 2: ['AAPL'], 3: ['AAPL', 'MSFT'], 4: ['MSFT'], 5: ['MSFT']}
```